# input text field with long text increases table cell in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have a table in which the second column should have a certain width (50px for example).
When I have a textbox with a width of 100% in this column, but with a lot of text, the width of the column is always as long as the text.

see my code + screenshot

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>


<table border="1">
  <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td style="width:50px;"><input type="text" value="very long text which doesn't fit into the whole textbox" style="width:100%" />
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

How can I force the column to be 50px long in IE7?

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve this by using IE conditional comments as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Test</title>    
    <style>
        .myInput{width: 100%;}
    </style>
    <!--[if IE 7]>
        <style>          
            .myInput{width: 50px;}
        </style>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td style="width:50px;"><input class="myInput" type="text" value="very long text which doesn't fit into the whole textbox"/>
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I have checked this on IE tester as and looks fine. Hope this helps!